# How do I know the name of an image I clicked on that has a macro assigned to it

Tags: excel, vba

I have an image with the assigned name 'boo', represented as a `shape` in my excel document. I have a macro assigned to 'boo'. When I click the boo image to activate the macro, I'd like to be able to know the `.name` of the image I clicked.

`selection.name` did not work, as clicking an image that has a macro is not the same as selecting an image with `.select`.

In essence, if I click on an image to activate the assigned macro, how can I find out the name of the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using `Application.Caller` With Shapes

- Add this code to your procedure. The worksheet needs to be active (selected) to get the information, it won't work when run from VBE but with the `If` statement you will avoid the error.

```vb
Sub TestCaller()
    
    Dim iName As String
    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "String" Then
        iName = Application.Caller
        MsgBox "The procedure was called from '" & iName & "'.", vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```